# How is the page number checked against the PT entries?

Tags: operating-system, paging, page-tables

In the book *Operating System Concepts by Silberschatz et al.* and in other representations of paging, each **Page Table** (PT) entry is shown to contain a **Frame Number**(FN). I have been trying to solve some problems on this topic and the solutions also assume the same.

[image]

I am new to this topic and all I've read is that the PT (or part of it) is usually stored in the physical memory. This means that the PT must start at some particular physical address. This value is stored in the **PTBR**. So when the CPU generates a logical address which is divided into a **Page Number**(PN) and the offset, the PN must be compared against it's value in the PT to determine the corresponding FN, right? Suppose, p=14. Now, 14, in its binary form, must be checked in the PT to find the entry 14.

So, does this mean that some bits of each entry of the PT store the PN and the rest of them store the corresponding FN? Then what about the problems which calculate the PT size assuming that it's only a multiple of the number of bits of the FN and completely ignore the PN bits? Or is it that since the values in the PT are stored in increasing order of PN, some calculations are performed on the PTBR to get the particular PT entry? If so, once the calculation to access the particular PT entry has been done, how is the memory access switched from the base address in the PTBR to the 'n'th entry? What hardware is used for that switch?

Basically, what I'd like to know is, where is the index, p(page number), which checks for the corresponding FN stored? How exactly is this value checked against the PT entries to get the FN?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Physical Page Frames are stored sequentially in hardware.

A logical address consists of a logical page number and an offset into the page. For page translation, we can ignore the offset.

In the simplest case, the page table is an array of Page Table Entries. The Logical Page Number serves as an indicate into this table.

The Page Table Entry may or may not have a value for a Physical Page Frame.

> This means that the PT must start at some particular physical address.
>   The address and size of the Page Table is usually specified by hardware registers.
>
> So when the CPU generates a logical address which is divided into a Page Number(PN) and the offset, the PN must be compared against it's value in the PT to determine the corresponding FN, right?

You appear to be describing an INVERTED PAGE TABLE that is used on a few processors. In most systems the Page Number is an index into the table. There is no comparison.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I did read about inverted page tables but they are ordered with respect to the physical addresses while the general idea of a page table is based on a sequential ordering of the page number. My question is, how is this indexing achieved with hardware? I mean, if the page number is 14 and the page table starts at 0, how does the index change to access that particular memory location?

Comment: In what type of page table?

Comment: Is there any name for a simple page table? If not, how does it work with hierarchical page tables? The first level page number will be indexed into a table right? How exactly will the value be searched for in the table? What sequence of steps take place on the hardware side?

Comment: A hierarchical table works in the same basic way as a linear table does. The difference is that the logical address is broken down into multiple indices that are used to walk the page table tree.

Comment: Yes buddy, I understand the theoretical concept perfectly but I don't understand how it works when implemented. You said the logical address is broken down. So now, the leftmost part of the divided logical address will be an index into the first level page table, right? So how is this particular operation performed by the hardware? What registers are changed, what happens to the PTBR, how does the concept of indexing work practically?

Comment: Let's say you have a 32-bit address where 24 bits are the page index and you have a three level table in which 8 bits are used in each level. The high-order 8 bits are an index into the top level table. That entry points to the next level table. The next 8-bits are an index into that table. That entry is another pointer to a table. The next 8-bits are an index into that table the gives the actual page table entry.

Comment: "The high-order 8 bits are an index into the top level table." So the index is implemented as a pointer to the table? And is it incremented by one page table entry until the corresponding frame table is found?

Comment: It is an index into an array.

Comment: Oof, I finally got it. Thank you lots for explaining my doubts with so much patience. I was going in circles over this simple concept despite your answer explaining it clearly. Apologies!